# com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential is now deprecated

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-vision

Google's [sample code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/vision/label/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/vision/samples/label/LabelApp.java) for the vision API shows this:

```
  public static Vision getVisionService() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    GoogleCredential credential =
        GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault().createScoped(VisionScopes.all());
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    return new Vision.Builder(GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(), jsonFactory, credential)
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
            .build();
  }
```

But `com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential` is now deprecated. What is the correct way to authenticate the above now?

Comment: What is the URL to the sample code.  Maybe we can raise an issue to get the sample updated?

Comment: @Kolban now above

Comment: A GitHub issue has been opened to ask that the sample be updated ... https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/issues/1942

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a couple ways.

Option 1:

1. Follow the steps on this [quickstart page](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/setup#sa-create)
2. Set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` which is something the client library uses by default

Option 2:

1. Load the service key file yourself.

```
// imports
import com.google.api.gax.core.FixedCredentialsProvider;
import com.google.auth.Credentials;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.ImageAnnotatorClient;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.ImageAnnotatorSettings;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

// somewhere in your code, load the credentials
try {
  Credentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(
        new FileInputStream("path_to_file.json"));

  FixedCredentialsProvider fixedCredentialsProvider =
        FixedCredentialsProvider.create(credentials);

  ImageAnnotatorSettings settings = 
        ImageAnnotatorSettings.newBuilder()
           .setCredentialsProvider(
               fixedCredentialsProvider).build();

  ImageAnnotatorClient client = 
        ImageAnnotatorClient.create(settings);
catch(IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace(e);
}
```

Comment: How would we use the accessToken stored after a user gives permission to our app?